# How to determine a point in $\mathbb{R}^3$ which is which is equidistant to three pairs of point?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a three pairs of points namely : $p_{1,1}, p_{1,2}, p_{2,1}, p_{2,2}, p_{3,1}, p_{3,2}$, I want to find $p$ such that : $|p-p_{i,1}| = |p-p_{i,2}|$ for all $i$.

I know that these represent three planes, but I am not sure whether these planes do meet in a single point. My simple question is even if the three planes are not parallel do they always meet in a single point. Intuitively I can visualize three planes which are not parallel but don't meet at a single point but how do I know that mathematically ?

Comment: Three nonparallel planes can intersect in an entire line.

Answer (score 5):

The planes described by the equations $z=0$, $z=y$, and $z=2y$ have the $x$-axis in common, so you may have infinitely many points.  The planes described by the equations $z=0$, $z=y$, and $z=1-y$ have no points in common, but no two are parallel.

One way to determine whether the given planes will have a unique point of intersection is using linear algebra.  Given the equations $a_1x+b_1y+c_1z=d_1$, $a_2x+b_2y+c_2z=d_2$, and $a_3x+b_3y+c_3z=d_3$ describing the planes, there is a unique solution to the system of equations, corresponding to the point where the planes meet, if and only if the coefficient matrix
$$A= \begin{bmatrix}
  a_1 & b_1 & c_1 \\
  a_2 & b_2 & c_2 \\
  a_3 & b_3 & c_3
\end{bmatrix}$$
has an inverse, in which case the solution is

$$\begin{bmatrix}
  x\\
  y \\
  z
\end{bmatrix}
=A^{-1}
\begin{bmatrix}
  d_1\\
  d_2 \\
  d_3
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Comment: Equivalently, check if the determinant of that matrix is zero.